# Javascript - Adding class to element from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to add classes to an element in order from an array. I have three different classes, and I am not sure how to loop back to the beginning of the array to start over when I get to the end of the array of classes. Here is what I have so far:

```
var backgrounds = ["gray", "red", "blue"];
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("blogpost");
var x = 0;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].classname += backgrounds[i];  //This is where I do not know how to add the elements in order
    x++; //This will get to the end of the array, how do I loop back to the beginning of the array after hitting the last element?
}
```

Comment: so you want the first one to be gray, second red, third blue, fourth great, fifth red, etc?

Comment: `x = ++x % backgrounds.length` will reset it, though you need `backgrounds[x]` instead of `backgrounds[i]`

Comment: or just `i%backgrounds.length` and disregard `x` all together. i is also incrementing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use modulo.

If you want classes like `blogspot red` then go with:

```
var backgrounds = ["gray", "red", "blue"];
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("blogpost");
var len = backgrounds.length;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].className += ' ' + backgrounds[i%len];
}
```

It gets a little more interesting if you want classes like `blogspotred`, though.
`getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array, but instead a node list, which will change once you start changing the classes (keep in mind, `blogspotred` doesn't fall under `blogspot` anymore). In that case you can, for example, do the following:

```
var backgrounds = ["gray", "red", "blue"];
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("blogpost"));
var len = backgrounds.length;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].className += backgrounds[i%len];
}
```

Comment: i really like the OP's question, and i would love to see how it's answered, but your solution doesn't seem to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nSXQ8/ - is it because it needs to be called ondomready?

Comment: that's because in your jsfiddle, you don't actually set the background colour anywhere, you just call a string with that colour

Comment: that's not the way i'm checking it - i'm looking at dev tools and the class names are not added... i see why (someone else said somewhere here already): `classname` should read `className`... but when i do that, your solution concatenates with the existing one and skips every other element...

Comment: it should be `elements[i].className += ' ' + backgrounds[i%len];`, then it works, see http://jsfiddle.net/nSXQ8/2/

Comment: Edited answer to address the above concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mod. instead of using `backgrounds[i]`, use `backgrounds[i%3]` where 3 is the length of the array

EDIT: in case you aren't aware of what that does, it gives the remainder. so first 0%3 is 0, then 1%3 is 1, 2%3 is 2, 3%3 is 0, 4%3 is 1, so on and so forth

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is not a loop, but a modulus:

```
var backgrounds = ['gray', 'red', 'blue'];
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('blogpost');
for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    // the following could be slightly optimized by storing the value to
    // backgrounds.length before the loop starts
    elements[i].className += ' ' + backgrounds[i%backgrounds.length];
}
```

Using `i%3` gives you the remainder of your `i` iterator divided by 3.  So, 0 -> 0, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 0, and so on.

Edit: Added correction from comments, and used superior choice to dynamically mod on the length of the array rather than static `3`.

Comment: think you're making the same mistake as Nit: `classname` should read `className` ;)... but even then, same issue as with Nit's answer: class concatenated with existing one and only added to every other... see http://jsfiddle.net/nSXQ8/1/

Comment: I have a feeling we both just copied directly from the OP, it's been a while since I've worked directly with class manipulation in native javascript, much preferring jQuery's methods for this myself.

Comment: well, for the sake of others seeing this and the correctness of an answer, you may want to edit it...